# FFMpeg adding automatic Beep sound at specific seconds

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

merging two audio files using ffmpeg but it's adding slight beep voice on specific duration everytime. Can we remove this?

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.wav -stream_loop 23 -i Wav_868kb.wav \
  -filter_complex "[0:0]volume=2.5[a];[1:0]volume=0.5[b];\
                   [a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" \
  output12.mp3
```

Comment: Is the beep interval related to the duration of looping audio track?

Comment: It's adding beep after 29 seconds but it's always added beep in different time if we changed audio.

Comment: OK... So with the audio files which produced 29-second beeping, is the second audio file 29 seconds long too?

Comment: One unrelated comment. You don't need `volume` filters as you can use the `weights` option of the `amix` filter: `-filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]amix=inputs=2:weights=2.5|0.5:duration=longest"`. (Your issue may be related to this, as it could be a volume saturation issue.)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.